# Update table if exist else insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named a

```
userindex bts   userid          accountnumber   isalepo
119459  190900  a@qubee.com.bd  000000000000004 0
31513   1a1430  b@qubee.com.bd  000000000000008 0
36981   196100  c@qubee.com.bd  000000000000018 0
56215   197200  d@qubee.com.bd  000000000000062 1
145938  199000  e@qubee.com.bd  000000000000066 0
57410   1a1520  f@qubee.com.bd  000000000000067 1
38554   198510  g@qubee.com.bd  000000000000068 0
15595   1a2d10  h@qubee.com.bd  000000000000069 0
30945   1a1120  i@qubee.com.bd  000000000000074 0
156180  190320  j@qubee.com.bd  000000000000081 0
```

I want to update only bts field if it exist in table b

```
userindex   bts usage_in_mb
100024  081620  4761.23809814
100044  001320  499.27043915
36981   19f710  1114.07279968
100061  19fb10  10931.33640284
57410   07dc10  108.45470429
100088  164610  1474.35951231
10009   19b700  2920.20797732
100105  19c200  7607.14340212
100110  000610  5771.08287813
156180  194820  1409.85393525
```

If userindex not exist in table a then i want to insert (userindex, bts,userid       ,accountnumber,isalepo) from b and c table. table c contains

```
userindex   accountnumber   userid
100024  000000000094190 aa@qubee.com.bd
100044  000000000000018 bb@qubee.com.bd
36981   000000000000067 cc@qubee.com.bd
100061  000000000214989 dd@qubee.com.bd
57410   000000000187084 ee@qubee.com.bd
100088  000000000236716 ff@qubee.com.bd
10009   000000000211229 gg@qubee.com.bd
100105  000000000236222 hh@qubee.com.bd
100110  000000000237036 ii@qubee.com.bd
156180  000000000000081 jj@qubee.com.bd
```

I am trying this query

```
INSERT INTO a
  (
   userindex
  ,bts
  ,userid
  ,accountnumber
  ,isalepo
  ,crestelbts
)
SELECT b.userindex
,b.bts
,c.USERID
,c.accountnumber
,1
,0
FROM b  
left join  c on b.userindex=c.userindex
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
bts = VALUES(b.bts);
```

Comment: What is the problem in your query and what did you get with this query any error or something else?

Comment: It append all data not update where userindex is same @Chonchol Mahmud

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please edit the tags.

Comment: Its for MySQL. I edit the tag

Comment: Do you want to accomplish this in a single query ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a **UNIQUE** index or **PRIMARY KEY**, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row. For example, if column a is
>   declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two
>   statements have similar effect:

This behaviour is because you don't have a unique or primary key. So you need to

```
ALTER TABLE a ALter table fts add primary key(userindex)
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE a ALter table fts add unique key(userindex)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) of MySQL, 
You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO a (userindex,bts,userid,accountnumber,isalepo,crestelbts) 
 SELECT b.userindex ,b.bts ,c.USERID ,c.accountnumber ,1 ,0
FROM b left join  c on b.userindex=c.userindex
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.userindex = a.userindex) OR (
   SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.userindex = a.userindex ));
```

Comment: i also want to update the bts in table 'a' from table 'b' @Amranur Rahman